# HTML5 - How to just draw the finished canvas/image

Tags: javascript, image, html, canvas, game-engine

I'm making a little game with HTML5 and MooTools and I have performance problems on firefox. I have implemented a counter to determine how often my `update` method gets called and it returns 64 times per second. The result seems much much slower (like 30 FPS). I think my problem is actually described on this article http://blog.sethladd.com/2011/03/measuring-html5-browser-fps-or-youre.html. I couldn't find out a way to solve this directly, but I think I can optimize the perforance.

I think one big problem in my logic is that I draw every single object on the canvas directly. I have done some games in Java before and I had great performance improvements with manipulating an image (drawing in the memory) and drawing just the final image. This way the browser would have much less requests to draw something and perhaps draw faster.

Is there a way to do this? I have found some libraries for image manipulation in JavaScript, but I would like to do it myself.

I can't show you the full code, because the project is for school and because it is way too big (~1500 lines of code).

Comment: You're talking about "buffered output".

Comment: Well, to start, you should be using `requestAnimationFrame` and not `setTimeout`. You can do some micro-optimizing by not redrawing everything, and only redrawing things that need to be updated (sometimes this isn't really possible depending on the nature of the game). You can also do some intelligent optimization with layering (don't draw stuff that would be drawn over by something else). But, without some actual code, we can't really give specific optimizations that you might be lacking.

Answer (score 2):

http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/canvas/performance/

Maybe this will help. It shows you how to improve performance by using an offscreen canvas to render your scene.

Comment: You all rock! Thank you really much, I think this is just what I was looking for! I will try it out tomorrow/the day after tomorrow and give feedback. I hope this works, this would just be fantastic. =D

Comment: Any news about the outcome? Has this improved the rendering by a lot?